How to extract date from a string and store it as date in another column
I have the following columns in my Excel sheet:

I need to pull a date from the string if it is there and store it in another column (Column C). It needs to be stored as a date so I can use this column and the column with due dates to calculate days difference between them Column D.
I used the following formula:
=TRIM(IFERROR(MID(" "&A1,FIND("/"," "&A1,1)-2,8),""))
This pulls the date portion from the text and removes unwanted stuff. However, I can't convert it into a date so can make the above calculation. I keep getting #VALUE error.
Can anyone help to resolve this?

The dates you are given are dd/mm/yyyy I assume from your column B that your local is mm/dd/yyyy?

what format have you set for Excel to recognise dates? edit your formula to produce that.

A format in the column B is m/d/yy so this is what I would like to use for the rest of the sheet. I am not getting this using the above function. Also, I am pulling some additional signs i.e. in row 3 I get 3/4/24-. However, when I try to clean it and convert it to the m/d/yy format it doesn't work.

The first row of your table includes the date "03/16/24". Your second row includes "18/02/24". These formats are obviously incompatible. Your third row contains "3/4/24" - is this 3rd April or 4th March? It's impossible to know.

I realize they are not consistent and hence my call for help as I can't figure out how to make them consistent in an efficient way. Forgive me if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks for all comments.

If you have a text string representing a date, Excel's VALUE() function will convert this into an "Excel date" (i.e. a numeric value representing the date). However, this will only work if the text date is in a format compatible with your operating system settings. There's no way to override this in Excel. If you have an incompatible date, you will need to manipulate the text, extract the individual elements and then create a date using Excel's DATE() function. Of course you'll still have problems if you can't distinguish between e.g. 3/4 and 4/3.

"I realize they are not consistent and hence my call for help as I can't figure out how to make them consistent in an efficient way. " - this is not possible. How will you decide what "3/4/24" means? But if you have a date that you know is in the wrong format, split it up (use e.g. SPLIT(), LEFT(), MID() etc) and then use DATE() to generate the date.

I multiplied your formula by one, *1 and it worked for me, just applied custom formatting from the ribbon. After reading the comments, I see that probably won't solve the issue.

Here's a way to get started:
Assuming you have Excel for Microsoft 365

Try to guess the date format and convert if possible
For dates marked as ambiguous, enter the month as text (for example "apr" or "April")
I've added a conditional formatting suggestion to highlight the ones that need changing
The formula "spills" the dates (no need to drag down)

In the first cell to get the date, enter the following (adjust the input range accordingly):
=LET(
    comments, A2:A6,
    get_date, LAMBDA(comment,
        LET(
            indices, SEQUENCE(LEN(comment)),
            digit_pos, IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(comment, indices, 1)), indices, ""),
            date_str, MID(comment, MIN(digit_pos), MAX(digit_pos) - MIN(digit_pos) + 1),
            date_part, --TEXTSPLIT(date_str, "/"),
            first, INDEX(date_part, 1, 1),
            second, INDEX(date_part, 1, 2),
            year_, INDEX(date_part, 1, 3) + 2000,
            IFERROR(
                IFS(
                    (ISERR(first) + ISERR(second)) * ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(date_str)),
                    DATEVALUE(date_str),
                    second > 12,
                    DATE(year_, first, second),
                    first > 12,
                    DATE(year_, second, first),
                    TRUE,
                    "Specify month as mmm"
                ),
                ""
            )
        )
    ),
    MAP(comments, get_date)
)



Hello I have tried to solve this in Excel 2021 but your dates from the comments are in all possibile ways - month/day/year or day/month/year and is hard to create the correct dates from this:
Formula in B2:
=IF(MIN(IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2," ",REPT(" ",255)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2))*255,255),"-",""),".","")),""))=0,
MID(A2,SEARCH("/",A2)-2,8),
MIN(IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2," ",REPT(" ",255)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2))*255,255),"-",""),".","")),"")))


Formula in D2:
=IF(ISNUMBER(C2),C2,DATE(20&RIGHT(C2,2),MID(C2,4,2),LEFT(C2,2)))


Hope it helps.
